# docker, container is not running

Tags: docker

`docker ps` shows instances, but when I try to log in to the instance, it says it's not running?

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                          COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
eaa62ff2df11        monitor_kibana                 "/usr/local/bin/dumb…"   4 months ago        Up 9 days                               kibana
613dc901f2e1        monitor_elasticsearch-search   "/usr/local/bin/dock…"   4 months ago        Up 9 days                               elasticsearch-search
$ docker exec -it eaa62 bash
Error response from daemon: Container eaa62ff2df11547744c5f7cf82cad16bf576820d2a209c4f19f173cca68f5511 is not running
$
```

Comment: Did you try to connect by name?

Comment: There is no such container `eaa62` in running container. you can check that in stop container `docker ps -a | grep eaa62`.

Comment: Use full container ID: `docker exec -it eaa62ff2df11  bash`

Comment: If you were running Kibana directly on your host outside of Docker, how would you "log in" to it?  I wouldn't spend a lot of time trying to debug `docker exec`.  What's the larger problem you're trying to solve this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be that the container only runs for a very short time? If you use the -a flag in your statement to get only active containers, like so:

> docker ps -a

Does it still show up? It could be that it runs and just uses something like ECHO. In that case, because the program run succesfully the container is immediately terminated.

Is this an official image? If so, try to run the container without the -d (for deamon) flag. This should output the run information to terminal and give you some information on what is going on.

Answer (score -1):

sudo docker exec -it eaa62 bash

Comment: You can't `docker exec` into a container that isn't running, which is the initial question.